# AWS amplify environment variables vs AWS secrets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a react app which is deployed using AWS Amplify. I'm using Google maps in my application and I wanted to know the right place to put the Google Maps API key. I have read about AWS Amplify Environment variables where we can save the api key in key-value pairs. Also, I know that we have AWS Secrets, which is for saving private data.

**What is the right approach to save the API key in my use case? Is saving the api key in Amplify Environment variables safe enough? Or should I go for AWS secrets?**

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear on what you can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The google maps api [best practices include](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#no-apikey-in-code) (depends exactly what you are using):

- Store API keys and signing secrets outside of your application’s source code.
- Store API keys or signing secrets in files outside of your application's source tree.

[Amplify Environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html) are suited to store:

- Third-party API keys

since

> As a best practice, you can use environment variables to expose these configurations. All environment variables that you add are encrypted to prevent rogue access, so **you can use them to store secret information**.

So you can use them, as their are **native to Amplify**. AWS Secrets Manager is not natively supported by amplify, and you would have to add extra code to your backend to  to make use of them.

The important thing to note is that these `Amplify Environment variables` are only to be used by your **backend service**. Not by a front-end code.